# preserve line ending Windows Form Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, line-endings

I have a little problem using the windows forms `textbox` control, I populate the content using the value of an `XElement` object. The `xml` from where it origins is writing with windows line ending so I was having the hope that when I present this content in the `textbox` it will be correctly formated but it doesn't. Every line ending is missing and the content is presented in one big line.
I set the control to `multiline` previously but apparently this only permits to show more than one line but it has nothing to do with how it interprets the text that I pass to it.

What is the correct way to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

I found that is not a problem of the textbox is a problem of how i'm accesing the data. If i use an XElement i get only one big line and if i use an XmlElement i get the code well formatted. Here is the code:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        textBox1.Text = doc.Descendants("dos").Single().Value;

        XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        doc2.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        textBox2.Text = doc2.GetElementsByTagName("dos")[0].InnerText;
```

Then the question will be reformulated this way: How can i recover the text using an XElement preserving the line feeds?

Comment: So you are setting the Text property of the textbox? What exactly is the line ending that your xml text has? When I tried this just using \r\n the line break appears as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
XElement data = ...
myTextBox.Lines = data.Value.Split('\n');
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i just don't understand why it works, :D. If it is show in the textbox as only one concatenated line how can i separate it with the "\n" character? i mean that character do not exist in first instance so how? what is wrong in this thinking?

Comment: more explicitely if i do textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", doc.Descendants("dos").Single().Value.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray())); i get the inner text well formatted, but wait...i'm not doing anything! i'm spliting and joining with the same character, what i'm missing?